# Connection is Null JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

les quiero hacer una consulta que me esta trabando un poco, estoy haciendo un desarrollo en JAVA y Tomcat 9 y cuando quiero listar los servicios temporales de los socios me sale error de connection is null, abajo pongo el error. Cuando lo ejecuto individualmente me funciona bien la consulta.

> java.sql.SQLException: Connection is null.
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.checkOpen(DelegatingConnection.java:603)
> at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:296)
> at data.DataServicioTemporal.listarServicioTemporalSocio(DataServicioTemporal.java:153)
> at controlador.CtrlServicioTemporal.listarServicioTemporalSocio(CtrlServicioTemporal.java:34)
> at testing.Testing.main(Testing.java:42)

Tengo un pool de conexiones que use en otro desarrollo y me funcionó. Además uso 3 métodos similares y no me da este error.

```
public class Conector {
/* Se va a hacer un pool de conexiones para mejorar el rendimiento de las consultas */
    
    //Declaro las variables que voy a usar en la conexion 
    private final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String DB = "mpbmbbdd";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:";
    private final int PORT = 3306; 
    private final String USR = "root";
    private final String PSW = "root";
    
    //Creo la instancia de la unica variable que voy a usar despues
    private static Conector dataSource; 
    //Creo la variable que voy a usar para conectarme.
    private BasicDataSource bds = null;
    
    //Declaro el constructor del Conector
    private Conector() {
        //Declaro las variables para el pool de conexiones.
        bds = new BasicDataSource();
        bds.setDriverClassName(DRIVER);
        bds.setUsername(USR);
        bds.setPassword(PSW);
        bds.setUrl(URL+PORT+"/"+DB+"?serverTimeZone=UTC");
        
        //Declaro las configuración que quiero en el pool de conexiones.
        bds.setMinIdle(5); //Conexiones minimas inactivas
        bds.setMaxIdle(20); //Conexiones máximas inactivas
        bds.setMaxTotal(50); //Conexiones totales al pool
        bds.setMaxWaitMillis(10000); //Tiempo máx de espera, en este caso son 10 seg
        bds.setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(true); 
    }
    
    //Declaro el método que obtiene la instancia Conector, para usar.
    public static Conector getInstancia() {
        if(dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = new Conector(); 
            return dataSource;
        }
        else { return dataSource; }
    }
    
    //Declaro el método para abrir la conexion
    public Connection abrirConexion() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null; 
        conn = this.bds.getConnection();
        //System.out.println("Se abrio la conexion");
        return conn; 
    }
    
    //Declaro el método para cerrar la conexion
    public void cerrarConexion(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        //System.out.println("cierro la conexion");
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Y la consulta a la BBDD es la siguiente

```
public ArrayList<ServicioTemporal> listarServicioTemporalSocio(int idsocio, int idfamiliar){
        //Variables
        ArrayList<ServicioTemporal> lista = new ArrayList<ServicioTemporal>(); 
        ServicioTemporal s = null; 
        PreparedStatement stmt = null; 
        ResultSet rs = null; 
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM serviciossociostemporales WHERE IDSocio = ? "
                + "AND IDFamiliar = ? ORDER BY IDSerial";
        
        
        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
            stmt.setInt(1, idsocio);
            stmt.setInt(2, idfamiliar);
            
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(); 
            
            if(rs != null) {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    s = new ServicioTemporal(); 
                    s.setIDSerial(rs.getInt("IDSerial"));
                    s.setIDSocio(rs.getInt("IDSocio"));
                    s.setIDFamiliar(rs.getInt("IDFamiliar"));
                    s.setIDServicio(rs.getInt("IDServicio"));
                    s.setDescripcion(rs.getString("Descripcion"));
                    s.setCantidadAdherentes(rs.getInt("CantidadAdherentes"));
                    s.setImporte(rs.getFloat("Importe"));
                    s.setUltimaCuotaCobrada(rs.getInt("UltimaCuotaCobrada"));
                    s.setCantidadDeCuotas(rs.getInt("CantidadDeCuotas"));
                    lista.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally { cerrar(stmt, null); }
        return lista; 
    }
```

Edito y agrego las partes de código que salen en el error.

error 34 del CtrlServicioTemporal

> return dst.listarServicioTemporalSocio(idsocio, idfamiliar);

error 153 del DataServicioTemporal

> stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!
Saludos
Matias

Comment: Revisa las  líneas 34 y 153 en el método ``listarServicioTemporalSocio`` de la clase ``CtrlServicioTemporal``. Otro caso es que quizás el nombre del driver es incorrecto.

Comment: Buenos días Fernando, la linea 34 del ctrlServicioTemporal llama al metodo del DataServicioTemporal y la linea 153 es cuando conecto a la base de datos para hacer la consulta.

Comment: ¿De donde sacas `conn` en el método `listarServicioTemporalSocio`. No se ve dónde la declaras. Yo esperaría ver algo como `Connection conn = Conector. getInstancia().abrirConexion();`

Comment: Hola Jaime, esta en el constructor, declaro una variable Connection conn; y en el constructor de la instancia lo asigno. conn = Conector.getInstancia().abrirConexion(); .